# How to add multiple functions in one event of Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add multiple functions in one event **onclick**.

Like This.:

```
$("div").click( function() {
$("img").fadeOut();
$("font").hide();
$("table").show();
});
```

(copy pasted real code from comment:)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#noti_t").click(function() { 
    $("#noti_show").toggle(); 
    $("#noti_s").hide(); 
    var wholedata="clear=1"; 
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "noti_clear.php", data: wholedata, cache: false, }); 
    return false; 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: What you have contains multiple function (`.fadeOut, .hide, .show`) inside on `click` event.. Isn't that is what you want?

Comment: it was not working i show the real code....

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#noti_t").click( function() {
    $("#noti_show").toggle();
    $("#noti_s").hide();
    var wholedata="clear=1";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "noti_clear.php",
    data: wholedata,
    cache: false,
    });
    return false;
    });`
});

Comment: @Heart: You have a trailing comma in the object literal. Change `cache: false, });` to `cache: false });`.

Comment: thanks everybody man its working perfect now.... I just removed return false;

Answer (score 0):

You can either put plenty of code in one function:

```
$("div").click( function() {
  $("img").fadeOut();
  $("font").hide();
  $("table").show();
});
```

Or you can hook up several events handlers to the same event:

```
$("div").click( function() {
  $("img").fadeOut();
});

$("div").click( function() {
  $("font").hide();
});

$("div").click( function() {
  $("table").show();
});
```

jQuery handles the multiple handlers, i.e. you don't have to check if there already is an event handler when you hook up another handler.

The first way is of course better if you do this in one place. The second way is useful if you want to hook up the same event from different places in the code.